# Is there a way to get position of multiple instanced objects?

Tags: godot

My Root node was set up like this:

> World
>
> - Player
>
>   object
>
>   object2
>
>   object3
>
>   object4

My player has a certain area and when an object enters it prints out the position of the original object.
I tried using

```
get_node("/root/World/object").get_position()
```

But object is an instanced scene and I have several of them: `object2`, `object3`, `object4`. Even if `object2` enters the area of my player it still prints the position of the original object.

Comment: "/root/World/object" always leads to the same original object. Did you try to change the path to refer to the object you need? Also area entering signals carry information about object which entered. You could use it to get the object node relatively to node that participated in collision and was returned in area entering signal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add your "objects" to a Group (named "my_group" for  example).

Then call :

```
for object in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("my_group"):
    member.get_position()
    ...
```

.